# FileInputStream and FileOutputStream line by line

Tags: java

FileInputStream reads all bytes of a file and FileOutputStream writes allbytes to a file

which class do i use if i want to read all bytes of a file but line by line

so that

if fileA contains two lines

line1 
line2

then bytes of line1 and line2 are read seperately

same goes for FileOutputStream

Comment: "lines" implies text data.
"output stream" implies binary data.
Which is it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fredrik is right about `BufferedReader`, but I'd disagree about `PrintWriter` - my problem with `PrintWriter` is that it swallows exceptions.

It's worth understanding why `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` don't have any methods relating to lines though: the `*Stream` classes are about streams of binary data. There's no such thing as a "line" in terms of binary data. The `*Reader` and `*Writer` classes are about *text*, where the concept of a line makes a lot more sense... although a general `Reader` doesn't have enough smarts to read a line (just a block of characters) so that's where `BufferedReader` comes in.

`InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter` are adapter classes, applying a character encoding to a stream of bytes to convert them into characters, or a stream of characters to turn them into bytes.

So, you probably want a `BufferedReader` wrapping an `InputStreamReader` wrapping a `FileInputStream` for reading - then call [`readLine()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()). For writing, use a `BufferedWriter` wrapping an `OutputStreamWriter` wrapping a `FileOutputStream` - then call [`write(String)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write(java.lang.String)) and [`newLine()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine()). (That will give you the platform default line separator - if you want a specific one, just write it as a string.)

There's also the `FileReader` class which sort of combines `FileInputStream` and `InputStreamReader` (and `FileWriter` does the equivalent) but these always use the platform default encoding, which is almost *never* what you want. That makes them all but useless IMO.

Comment: I agree PrintWriter has drawbacks, but it was the one closest to the question. I started out suggesting a Writer but it really doesn't do "line by line". Good point though (+1).

Comment: @Fredrik: It's not your fault that the Java library designers decided to give PrintWriter too many responsibilities :(

Comment: @Jon: Thank you :-) I know that, I just wanted to explain why I recommended it anyway.

Answer (score 7):

I think what you are looking for is a BufferedReader and a PrintWriter.

Check out this one for a sample of the first: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/CreateBufferedReaderfromInputStreamReader.htm